# python-igraph how to add edges with weight?

Tags: python, igraph

python-igraph how to add edges with weight?

I have a tuple list like `[('1', '177', 1.0), ('1', '54', 1.0), ('1', '61', 2.0), ('1', '86', 2.0), ('10', '100', 38.0)]`. The last one in the tuple is the weight of edge from `'1'` to `'177'`.
But how to add it? I use

```
g.add_vertices(vertexList)
g.add_edges(edgelist)
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: I don't use igraph, but from the tutorial it seems like you need to add a "edge attribute."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We need to do some *pre-processing* first.

The following code works fine and does what you asked.

---

```
from igraph import *

# Here we have 5 edges
a = [('1', '177', 1.0), ('1', '54', 1.0), ('1', '61', 2.0), 
     ('1', '86', 2.0), ('10', '100', 38.0)]    

edge = []
weights = []
# the loop for i is in range(5) because you have 5 edges
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(2):
        k =2
        edge.append(a[i][j])
    weights.append(a[i][k])

edges = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(edge[::2], edge[1::2])]

list1 = []
for i in range(len(edges)):
    list1.append((int(edges[i][0]), int(edges[i][1])))

g= Graph()
g.add_vertices(178)
g.add_edges(list1)
g.es['weight'] = weights

g.ecount()
5

g.es['weight']
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 38.0]
```

Answer (score 7):

You have not longer "preprocess" data, becouse this format is accurate for new method:

```
g = Graph.TupleList([(from, to, weight], ...)
```

one more example from author:

```
g=Graph.TupleList([("a", "b", 3.0), ("c", "d", 4.0), ("a", "c", 5.0)], weights=True)
```

Method is available from version 0.6.1, what said author here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/igraph/+question/206397

Comment: How do I label the vertices using this method?

Comment: This method is only helper for wights. There is no one for labels. You can use standard constructor with attributes, as in the example from my link.
`g=Graph(edgelist, vertex_attrs=dict(name=ids.values()), edge_attrs=dict(weight=weights))`